# Orientation induced from inner and exterior

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I'm reading *From Calculus to Cohomology*, Chapter 11 Index of Vector Fields. In the proof of Theorem 11.22, $U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is an open subset, $D\subset U$ is a closed ball, then it says that the orientation of $\partial D$ induced from $U\backslash\mathrm{Int}(D)$, is opposite to the orientation induced from $D$.How do I check this?

Answer (score 0):

$D$ is a manifold with boundary, and the orientation on $\partial D$ is induced by a outward vector field, so if $D=B(0,1)$ for example the outward vector field is $v(x)=x$, on other hand, the outward vector field of $\partial D$ on $U-int(D)$ it's $u(x)=-x=-v(x)$ (Draw the situation), so the orientation it's opposite orientation.